# Sails global doesn't work in helpers when using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sails.js

I get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'sails'.` when trying to use `sails` global inside a ts helper. The sails global is enabled in the configuration, and this works when I change it to js.
This is my `api/helpers/is-admin-email.ts`.

```
module.exports = {
  friendlyName: 'Is admin email',

  description: 'Checks if the email is in admin email list',

  sync: true,

  inputs: {
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      example: 'example@email.com',
      description: 'the email to check with admin list',
      required: true,
    },
  },

  exits: {
    success: {
      description: 'Returns true if the email is in admin list',
    },
  },

  fn: function(inputs, exits) {
    const adminEmails: Array<string> = sails.config.custom.adminEmails;
    const isAdmin = adminEmails.includes(inputs.email);
    exits.success(isAdmin);
  },
};
```

Note: the `sails` global works fine in ts controllers.

Comment: Put these line - `declare var sails: any;` to top of `is-admin-email.ts` file. https://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-type-script